# Update state of a Product while submitting a form React/NextJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, e-commerce, cloudinary

I'm trying to update my product object when the submit button is clicked but it doesn't update in that render.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const media = await imageUpload(files); // function  returns an array of links
    setProduct((prev) => ({ ...prev, images: media })); // Here where I want to update the images but it doesn't work
    await createProduct();
    setProduct(initialState); // reset to default
  };
```

I tried using an useEffect to detect when the button is clicked and then update the product but it doesn't work too.

Hope I made myself clear.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: it might be because the useState hook is asynchron, and by the time you call CreatProduct, the setProduct call above hasn't finished its job, you cannot use  the value right away.
May be try adding await in front of your setProduct, or remove the creatProduct from your async call and place it inside of a useEffect wich will have your product as a dependency, so that when the product changes, , your createProduct function is called

Comment: Yeah it must be what you are saying. I must remove the createProduct because awaiting the setProduct doesn't work, I mean, I can't await it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be exctracting your CreateProduct function like so :

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const media = await imageUpload(files); // function  returns an array of links
    setProduct((prev) => ({ ...prev, images: media }));
  };

useEffect(()=>{
 if(product){
  createProduct();
  setProduct(initialState);
 }
},[product])
```

Comment: I forgot to say that my createProduct is an async function that POST the product to the DB. Also product is an object and with that useEffect is constantly trying to POST because product is always existing. That's why I cant fill the create form and its bugging.

Comment: do you ahave your whole code somwhere in a sandbox or something ?

Comment: I made it work by checking if all the keys of the product (title, price, category, etc) are filled, and then execute the createProduct as you commented. But one question, how does it know when the submit button is clicked, because I can fill all the form and it could self createProduct, because of the useEffect. But it worked as expected.

Comment: it might get a bit complex while it should be more simple...but the first thing that coming to my mind would be to have a variable called 'isValidate' that is false, and set to true only when the form is submitted, and in your useEffect use that variable to prevent the useEffect from beeing triggered if isValidate is false.  Most of the time, the hardest thing is to keep things simple. When the code become overcrowded with conditions that's when things gow wrong and become hard to maintain and scale.

Comment: Yeah thats my fear, also I did that with my EDIT form and it worked, cause now while editing the form, is filled with the DB data. But it worked, is it bad?